# Gas webhook that writes data to multiple spreadsheet of different users

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks

I have a crm where it can send sms responses to webhook (created from apps script)

The webhook script is deployed as anyone with the link can access
The webhook takes spreadsheet url as it's url parameter.
This spreadsheet has permission anyone with link can edit

Hence a webhook looks like
https://script.google..../exec?url=spreadsheeturl

All works good so far.

Now, I need the same webhook script to be used by all of my co workers and they have thier own crm logins which they need to specify their spreadsheet as parameter

Hence PersonA will write https://script.google..../exec?url=spreadsheeturlA

Person2
https://script.google..../exec?url=spreadsheeturlB

Person A and B are not willing to make the sheet anyone with link as edit as they are afraid of giving edit access to outsiders.

Is there a way where they can pass the login token as url parameter of personAs crm wrbhook url along with spreadsheetA url and validate to access the spreadsheetA instead of making spreadsheet anyone with link can edit?

UPDATE: I don't want myself to be added edit permissions by them.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Set `Execute as` :`User accessing`

Comment: What's the name of your CRM?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the context in which requests are made?

Answer (score 0):

When the app is deployed you can choose `execute as` and enter yourself as the executer. In that case, make sure that your colleagues have given you the edit rights to their Spreadsheets in question, eg. `Spreadsheet A`. When the app then runs, it is running as yourself and therefore should work. Or you can set the user as the one which is running the app. See here for more information:

[Web-App Permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions)

This is the window I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: Sorry if forgot to mention in my question I updated I don't want myself to be added edit permissions by them.

Comment: then pick the 2nd option from above, "User accessing the web app". See screenshot above.

Comment: If specified as user access, the crm cannot write sms as crm needs spreadsheet to be anyone with write access. The crm just needs webhook address and spreadsheet

Comment: @CodeGuy Create a dummy spreadsheet. Crm. writes to dummy -> your webapp gets the data and writes to original sheet.

Comment: Can't do that as messages are not allowed to be accessed by fellow users

Comment: Is there a way to pass auth token via url and Authorize a webapp each time it's being called?

Comment: You need to provide better contextual information in your description in order for us to support you. Going back and forth within comments is not useful.